# php explode() function issue - spaces

Tags: php, explode

I wish to split a text string into words separated by spaces.
I use

```
$words=explode(" ", $text);
```

Unfortunately, this method doesn't work well for me, because I want to know how many spaces are in between.

Is there any better way to do that than going through the whole $text, symbol by symbol, using `while` statement to fill out $spaces ( `$spaces=array();` ) with integers (number of spaces, in most cases it is 1) and read text into $words=array() symbol by symbol?

Here is an additional explanation.

```
$text="Hello_world_____123"; //symbol "_" actually means a space
```

Needed:

```
$words=("Hello","world","123");
$spaces=(1,5);
```

Comment: Regular expressions are your friend. :)

Comment: Hm... substr_count will give me 6 for the example above. preg_split to split by (any num of) will split the string into 3 words. How will I know 6=5+1, but not 3+3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you're trying to do, but I would probably choose a combination of [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$text = 'Hello world     123';
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $text, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$spaces = array_map(function ($sp) {
    return strlen($sp);
}, preg_split('/\S+/', $text, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

var_dump($words, $spaces);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "world"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Comment: That's elegant, compact and I believe it's fast (faster than using for statement I guess). It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression instead:

```
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $text)
```

**EDIT**

```
$spaces = array();
$results = preg_split('/[^\s]+/', $text);
foreach ($results as $result) {
  if (strlen($result) > 0) {
     $spaces [] = strlen($result);
  }
}
```

Comment: He just needs the number of spaces.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: I was blinded by the 'I wish to split a text string into words separated by spaces' part

Answer (score 0):

You can still get the number of spaces inbetween like this:

```
$words = explode(" ", $text);
$spaces = sizeof($words)-1;
```

Wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't say how many spaces are between each pair of words at all, even doesn't say the total number of spaces.

Comment: @Haradzieniec I thought you wanted to split up each word? What word has spaces in them? :/ The number of spaces is in $spaces `(number of words in array - 1)`

Comment: I put an explanation, an example into a question. Thank you.